# How to download and use only a specified font in font awesome

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, fonts, font-awesome

i try to use only a specified font(clip board) from font awesome,
here is my code which was in v4, but i need the clipboard from v5,

as previously in my code which was v4 used for other icons, when i try to include v5 icons it displays square for these icons,

so how to download and use only specified font(clip board)

here is my code

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';

  src: url("<%= asset_path 'fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.5.0' %>");

  src: url("<%= asset_path 'fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.5.0'%>") 
format('embedded-opentype'),

  url("<%= asset_path 'fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0'%>") format('woff2'),

  url("<%= asset_path 'fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.5.0'%>") format('woff'),

  url("<%= asset_path 'fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.5.0' %>") format('truetype'),

  url("<%= asset_path 'fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.5.0#fontawesomeregular'%>") 
format('svg');
  
}`
```

how to download and use clipboard icon which was in v 5

Comment: From [their document](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/upgrading-from-version-4#manually) you can use **v4-shim**.